# I said / have said

Tags: tense

Is it okay to use Present Simple after "I said" when reporting something that is still true/valid but was said some time ago? Like here (a conversation):

> A: You said you were scared to go...
>   B: Yes, but I said I want to go.

And what is the difference between I said... and I've said...?

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly ok to use "I said" in that example, and in fact is more likely to be used than "I've said" by native speakers.

"I said" would be used when the speaker want to say what they said:

> So I said that I thought it was a great idea...

"I've said" would be used when the speaker is not going to repeat exactly what they said, and often to back up a point:

> He's an idiot. I've said in the past that he shouldn't do that

Here also is a similar post on [“I have never said” versus “I never said”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15535/i-have-never-said-versus-i-never-said) that you might find helpful.