# What is the difference between “Have said” and “said”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have seen in news “ you have said”

“someone has said”

When to use “have said” ?

And

When to use “said”?

Comment: "He said" usually refers to a particular occasion. "At the press conference, Mr X said..." A journalist would use "He has said" to imply that the person has expressed that opinion at some time in the recent past, but without specifying exactly when.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163501/i-said-have-said